# WebApi - Getting the OAuth bearer token after context.Validated()

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

Simple one here i hope :) I have an OAuth token end point for an API, and it's all working perfectly, however, I want to store the token in the database.

In.....

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
```

I have the following code.....

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Username", context.UserName));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("IpAddress", context.OwinContext.Request.RemoteIpAddress));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("TokenReceivedDate", DateTime.Now.ToString()));

//  Now store the token in the database.

context.Validated(identity);
```

Can I get the bearer token that is to be issued at this point? Ideally i want to store this in the database for legacy applications to pick up. Digging through all the objects anything that *resembles* an object that (could) hold the token seems to be NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, by overriding the 'TokenEndPointReponse' you can easily dig out the Token that is produced.

```
public override Task TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)
{
    string thisIsTheToken = context.AccessToken;
    return base.TokenEndpointResponse(context);
}
```